# ObjC : NSLog a pointer name

Tags: objective-c, class, pointers, instance, nslog

I filled a NSMutableArray with 3 class instances I created. Now I want to iterate this array to get some variable values. I'm able to do so, but not able to print my instance name (bread, water, ...) Instead, I get their addresses.
I guess it's simple but I'm struggling a bit, so if someone knows how to ... 
Thank you

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StockHolding.h";

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

StockHolding *bread = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
[bread setPurchaseSharePrice:100];
[bread setCurrentSharePrice:120];
[bread setNumberOfShares:100];

StockHolding *water = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
[water setPurchaseSharePrice:100];
[water setCurrentSharePrice:80];
[water setNumberOfShares:10];

StockHolding *tomatoes = [[StockHolding alloc] init];
[tomatoes setPurchaseSharePrice:100];
[tomatoes setCurrentSharePrice:50];
[tomatoes setNumberOfShares:1];

NSMutableArray *myStock = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:bread, water, tomatoes, nil];

for (StockHolding *s in myStock)
{
    NSLog(@"Here is what I paid for my %p : %f", s, [s costInDollars]);
    NSLog(@"Here is what I earn for my %p : %f", s, [s valueInDollars]);

}

[pool drain];
return 0;
```

}

Comment: what is the data type of costInDollars & valueInDollars. Trying to print it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement the `-(NSString *)description` method on your StockHolding class? Then you can use `%@` in string formats and it will output the description there.

Alternatively you can also output any other string property of StockHolding instances with `%@`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to NSLog an object and it's pointer name you can add this #define in your preprocessor macro `#define OLog(x) NSLog(@"%s = %@",#x, x);`